# Error - If the target type is ALB, the target must have at least one listener that matches the target group port or any specified p ort overrides

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer, vpc-endpoint, aws-private-link, network-load-balancer

I am trying to develop a PrivateLink that will connect with ApplicationLoadBalancer

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as elb,
    aws_elasticloadbalancingv2_targets as elb_targets,
    aws_iam as iam)

target_group = elb.ApplicationTargetGroup(
        self,
        "tg-alb",
        target_group_name="tg-alb",
        target_type=elb.TargetType.INSTANCE,
        port=443,
        protocol=elb.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
        targets=[
            elb_targets.InstanceTarget(self.ec2_1, 443),
            elb_targets.InstanceTarget(self.ec2_2, 443)
        ],
    )

    alb = elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(
        self,
        id="alb",
        load_balancer_name="alb",
        vpc=self.vpc,
        internet_facing=False,
        security_group=self.security_group,
        vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
            subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
        ),
    )

    listener = alb.add_listener(
        id="listener",
        port=443,
        open=False,
        protocol=elb.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
        certificates=[
            elb.ListenerCertificate.from_arn(
                "<ARN_FULL_PATH>")
        ]
    )

    listener.add_target_groups("target", target_groups=[target_group])
```

ApplicationLoadBalancer deployed correctly, but I am getting the issues when I was trying to connect an ALB with NLB below -

```
Resource handler returned message: "If the target type is ALB, the target must have at least one listener that matches the target group port or any specified port overrides (Service: ElasticLoadBalancingV2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: exf1l9b0-f3f2-42de-9222-5088dd065edd)" (RequestToken: 9d316e0c-0cac-ccca-f1od-4837b1e54eaf, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

My NetworkLoadBalancer and EndpointService codes below -

```
nlb = elb.NetworkLoadBalancer(
        self,
        "nlb-eps",
        load_balancer_name="nlb-eps",
        vpc=self.vpc,
        internet_facing=False,
        vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
            subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
        )
    )

    network_target_group = elb.NetworkTargetGroup(
        self,
        "tg-nlb-eps",
        target_group_name="tg-nlb-eps",
        target_type=elb.TargetType.ALB,
        port=443,
        vpc=self.vpc,
        targets=[
            elb_targets.AlbTarget(self.alb, 443)
        ]
    )

    # Add listener on a particular port
    listener = nlb.add_listener(
        id="listener-nlb-eps",
        port=443
    )

    listener.add_action(
        "action-nlb-eps",
        action=elb.NetworkListenerAction.forward(
            target_groups=[network_target_group]
        )
    )

    endpoint_service = ec2.VpcEndpointService(
        self, "eps-alb",
        vpc_endpoint_service_load_balancers=[nlb],
        acceptance_required=True,
        allowed_principals=[
            iam.ArnPrincipal("<ARN_DETAILS")
        ]
    )
```

Could anyone please help me to solve the issue?